# Insincere (Erev Yom Kippur) mechila

Tags: halacha

There are those who say that even if someone  was only moichel Erev Yom Kippur because he was a pushover or embarrassed not to, the story is over. Once the  aggrieving party was told that he has mechila he no longer has any obligation to make effort to receive mechila. Others disagree.

I'm looking for sources either way on this question. Either of places where this question is discussed. Or proof either way from Gemorah or Rishonim.

Comment: I’m not sure about this case, but with regards to money, Mechillah because of embarrassment would not work (see Rashi on the Mishnah in Kesubos 104b)